# VBA StrConv with vbNarrow throw Run-time eror '5'

Tags: excel, vba, strconv

I have an excel file which work well with Excel 2007, now my company upgrade all PC to Windows 10 Enterprise v1809 and Office 2016, then it got error `runtime error 5`.

Here is my code, the error throw from StrConv line,

Tried Google but no help, is there anyway may help me fix this problem?

---

Update 1:

I'm working with many Japanese documents so I've changed my system locale to Japanese (in Control Panel/Region/Administrative/System Locale)

Update 2:

I don't want to convert Kanji (Chinese characters in my source), I want to convert double-byte English characters (`１Ｆ－２Ｆ`) to single-byte English character (`1F-2F`)

```vb
Public Sub 階段問合せ書作成()

Dim Kaidan1 As Worksheet
Dim N_ws As Workbook
Dim WB As Workbook

    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook


    jigyousyo = Range("事業所")
    kaidan_name1 = StrConv(Range("階数①").Value, vbNarrow)
    kaidan_name2 = StrConv(Range("ŠK”‡A").Value, vbNarrow)
```

[image: debug info]

[image: strconv runtime error 5]

[image: my system locale is Japanese]

Comment: On the [Microsoft documentation-page for `StrConv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strconv-function), it says the constant `vbNarrow` _"cause a run-time error when used in locales where it does not apply."_ Could that be the case here?

Comment: What's the result you expect from StrConv in this case? The Chinese characters of your original string are 2-byte characters by nature. How could they be converted to 1-byte characters?

Comment: @eirikdaude : I've checked that point so I've already changed  my System Locale to Japanese.

Comment: @Variatus : I've updated my question, the string which I want to convert is not those Chinese characters, they are double-byte english characters `１Ｆ－２Ｆ`

Comment: Sorry. Actually, that was quite clear. I was confused. Would you need help with a loop to test which of the characters don't translate to single byte?

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of the function is

```
StrConv(string, conversion, [ LCID ])
```

Instead of

```
StrConv(Range("階数①").Value, vbNarrow)
```

You may use this instead.

```
StrConv(Range("階数①").Value, vbNarrow, 1041)
```

1041 is Locale ID of Japan.
No matter what the system locale and Format in your PC is set to, it should work.

Comment: Passing the Locale ID 1041 worked for me.  I'm in America processing Excel files from Japan.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `System Locale` and `Format` in `Region` to `Japanese`

Comment: thanks for your reply but I can't confirmed the problem's root cause & answer because other vendor has fixed it.

Comment: Yes, Answers for who need later.